# Bazaar VCS on Windows Shared Hosting

Tags: windows, version-control, shared-hosting, bazaar

Is it possible to use Bazaar on my windows shared hosting without SSH access?
http://bazaar.canonical.com/en/

If it is possible, can you please explain how to set it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example if you setup a domain `bzr.example.com` on the Windows server with its document directory in `/websites/bzr.example.com`, then you could push your bzr project with:

```
bzr push ftp://username:password@server/websites/bzr.example.com/project1 --create-prefix
```

And your friends can branch from it read-only via:

```
bzr branch http://bzr.example.com/project1
```

Answer (score 0):

If your provider supports uploading with [ftp or sftp](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/beta/en/user-reference/urlspec-help.html), you can use that. How do you upload files normally?

Comment: Ok, so you can push your branch up with eg. `bzr push ftp://yourserver/path` . This is fine for if you just want to host the branch but note that the branch content will not be visible (you will just see a .bzr directory). I see that unfortunately for you the bzr-automirror and bzr-push-and-update plugins require ssh in order to update the branch content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http or ftp protocol for your concern.

- **http** : simple http browsing is ok for read-only access.
- **ftp** : to add write acess, ftp is ok.

See documentation here:
http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.2.5/en/admin-guide/other-setups.html

Comment: How do I create the Branch via FTP?

Comment: `bzr push ftp://username:password@server/path/to/repo --create-prefix`